# Use HttpWebRequest to post xml data to CDC Service fails

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm using the HttpWebRequest to post the soap xml data to the CDC service but it returns the error message as 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()' can someone helps me please?

```
protected string PostXMLToCDCService()
        {
            string retStatus = "", responseStr = "";

            try
            {
                //set the TLS 1.2 version
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method 
                System.Xml.XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
                //Use HttpWebRequest to post XML 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService");
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soapEnvelopeXml.InnerXml.ToString());
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.SendChunked = true;
                request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8; ";
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "urn:cdc:iisb:2011:submitSingleMessage"); 
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Timeout = 1000000000;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000000;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  //Error: (400) Bad Request
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                }
                retStatus = responseStr;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retStatus = ex.ToString();
            }

            return retStatus;
        }
```

Sample xml data:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:cdc:iisb:2011">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<urn:submitSingleMessage> <urn:username>abcxx</urn:username> <urn:password>xxx</urn:password>
<urn:facilityID>Facility Name </urn:facilityID> <urn:hl7Message><![CDATA[INSERT xxxxx MESSAGE]]></urn:hl7Message>
</urn:submitSingleMessage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: If you want to call a SOAP service why do you use HttpWebRequest? Why not use WCF to create a proxy class from its WSDL? .NET offers SOAP web service support since 2002 - in fact SOAP was created by Microsoft. Go to the `References` node of your project, right click and select `Add Service Reference`

Comment: BTW there's no reason to explicitly set the TLS version in supported OSs and recent .NET versions

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for replying. Do you have a sample of WCF on how to call and post xml data? I did try to add reference to the endpoint URL at https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService and it couldn't located. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Unlike JSON/HTTP, SOAP messages are well-defined, with all operations specified in WSDL files, all DTOs specified in XSD files. There are specific protocols for security, authentication etc which means it's possible to create a client just from the WSDL file.

Comment: There are *hundreds* of books, tutorials, courses, blog posts, articles going back 18 years. As I said, all you have to do is right click on `References`, select `Add Service Reference` and type the WSDL URL.

Comment: The method is "submitSingleMessage " and the endpoint URL is "https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService", when I tried to add reference to this service and receives the error message "There was an error downloading 'https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: These are the 3 web addresses that I tried:    "https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService"  
"https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService?op=submitSingleMessage"  
"https://xxxxxxxxxx/CDCService/submitSingleMessage"

Comment: If you don't know the URL of the WSDL file then ask the provider of the API to tell you. We can't guess it for you. Most likely it will end in .wsdl though.